# How to get the session object in general from within a class?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

There is a class :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.ambre.pta")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/global.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/main.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/admin.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/referentiel.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/departement.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/exercice.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/defi.properties")
})
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {

        BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();

        bds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        bds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");

        bds.setUsername("pta");
        bds.setPassword("pta");

        return bds;

    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

        sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.ambre.pta.model");

        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();

    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);

        return transactionManager;

    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "utilisateurDao")
    public UtilisateurDAO getUtilisateurDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new UtilisateurDAOImpl(sessionFactory);
    }

}
```

We can get the `request` object within this class by this way :

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

So is there a way to get the `session` ( HttpSession ) object ?

Comment: _"How to get the session object in general from within a class?"_ Don't do that. But if you insist: `request.getSession()` ...

Comment: request.getSession().setAttribute i set some attribute. On next url hit session.getAttribute become null. Any Idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using Controller classes

You can define `HttpSession` as an argument to your controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping("/my-path")
public String doStuff(HttpSession session) {
    // do stuff...
}
```

This is also the recommended way to access the `HttpRequest`, rather than going through `RequestContextHolder`, because it's easier to mock out the session for tests.

See [the Spring MVC docs for more detail.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments)

## Without using controller classes

Another option is to use a `@SessionScope` bean and mutate it accordingly:

```
@Component
@SessionScope
public class MySessionScopedBean {
    String attribute;
}

public class MyOtherClass {
    @Autowired
    private MySessionScopedBean myBean;

    public void doStuff() {
        // myBean accesses a bean instance isolated in the user session
        myBean.attribute = "test";
    }

}
```

Comment: but I have a special need to access session within a non-controller class !

Comment: What, specifically, do you need to get from the session?

Comment: Oops, accidentally posted. 

If you need to keep some sort of user session state, my advice would be to create a `@SessionScope` bean.
This way, you can inject it into a non-controller bean.

Comment: I stored 2 attributes in the session after a successfull login. So I need to get these values in my config class.

Comment: In that case, I think using session scoped beans and mutating them would be the way to go, since it's more readable than storing attributes directly in the session.
Otherwise, I'd use a controller method that receives the session (or attribute in the session, which is also possible) and pass it into the component.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the HttpSession outside a Controller method, there are two possible answers:

1. Don't do it, it's evil.
2. If you really really want to do it (and I have done it in the past, so who am I to blame you), then the easiest way is to write a class to hold the session, and an interceptor to set and unset it. But to make things easier, I will be working with HttpServletRequest objects, from which you can extract the session:

   ```
   public class RequestHolder {

       private static final ThreadLocal<HttpServletRequest> REQUEST =
                                new ThreadLocal<>();

       public static HttpServletRequest getCurrentRequest() {
           return REQUEST.get();
       }

       public static HttpSession getCurrentSession() {
           HttpServletRequest request = REQUEST.get();
           return request == null ? null : request.getSession();
       }

       public static void setCurrentRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
           REQUEST.set(request);
       }

       public static void unsetCurrentRequest() {
           REQUEST.remove();
       }

   }

   public class RequestHolderInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
       @Override
       public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object o) {
           RequestHolder.setCurrentRequest(request);
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object o, ModelAndView mav) {
       }

       @Override
       public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object o, Exception e){
           RequestHolder.unsetCurrentRequest();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Could you please explain in a few words why is it evil? I read everywhere that it is so, but without any explanations. How Controller classes are different than other Components?

Comment: @gdrt that's hard to explain, but in an MVC app, each layer should be specialized. The M should be business only, independent of the frontend technology calling it, whereas the V layer should deal with presentation only.